# Equivalent of Java's getBytes in JavaScript for different encodings

Tags: javascript, arrays, encoding, decoding, windows-1252

I have a function in Java that I need to convert to JavaScript and that contains this line:

```
byte[] bytes = ttText.getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp1250"));
```

`ttText` is String. I need to do the same. I need to get the bytes of a string encoded in Cp1250 (windows-1250), **modify those bytes** and then convert it back to string. Is there a way how to do it in JavaScript?

I discovered for example [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) and [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) but the support for different encodings than UTF-8 was dropped some time ago.

Answer (score 3):

```
var cp1250 = '€ ‚ „…†‡ ‰Š‹ŚŤŽŹ ‘’“”•–— ™š›śťžź ˇ˘Ł¤Ą¦§¨©Ş«¬­®Ż°±˛ł´µ¶·¸ąş»Ľ˝ľżŔÁÂĂÄĹĆÇČÉĘËĚÍÎĎĐŃŇÓÔŐÖ×ŘŮÚŰÜÝŢßŕáâăäĺćçčéęëěíîďđńňóôőö÷řůúűüýţ˙';

function encodeCP1250(text) {
  var buf = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var code = cp1250.indexOf(text[i]);
    if (code >= 0) {
      code += 128;
    } else {
      code = text.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    buf.push(code > 255 ? 32 : code);
  }
  return buf;  
}

function decodeCP1250(buf) {
  var text = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    var code = buf[i];
    text += code > 127 ? cp1250[code - 128] : String.fromCharCode(code);
  }
  return text;  
}

var buf = encodeCP1250('AÁÂĂÄ'); // [65, 193, 194, 195, 196]
var text = decodeCP1250(buf);    // 'AÁÂĂÄ'
```

**Upd:** Chrome and Firefox have [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) as experimental feature, but TextEncoder works only with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
https://mths.be/windows-1250

This looks promising. It provides support for both encoding and decoding.
All you need to do is add the library and use the methods.
var encodedData = windows1250.encode(text);

Comment: Thanks, I found this as well but it's only for encoding/decoding. I need to get the actual bytes to modify them. Encode to bytes -> modify bytes -> decode back.

Comment: I have one question. If you modify the encoded bytes you won't be getting the same result back after decoding.

Comment: Yes, of course, I know. That's why I need to modify them. I need to apply a certain mapping function to those bytes to get a different result.

Comment: I'm using an external API which returns a certain character. I need to print out this character on the web using a special image/icon font. Every character I'm getting from the API has an image representation in the image font, however, only certain characters match their font counterparts without modification. To match also the others I must do something like (bytes[i] & 0xFF) + 0xF000) for each byte. Well ... so there's no way to do this in JavaScript? :-/

Comment: You lost me there. Someone will sure help you, there must be a way. I am adding up point to your question.